# Segmentation fault problem in C (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct arrayADT {

  int *A;
  int size;
  int length;
  int *B;
  int arr3;
};
struct arrayADT * MergeArray(struct arrayADT *arr1, struct arrayADT *arr2) {    //we create thus in heap cuz we need to be able to use these in main function
  
  struct arrayADT *arr3 = (struct arrayADT *)malloc((sizeof(struct arrayADT)));

  int i, j, k;
  i = j = k = 0;

  while(i < arr1->length && j < arr1->length ) {
    if(arr1->A[i] < arr2->A[j]) {
      arr3->A[k] = arr1->A[i];
      k++;
      i++;
    }

    else {
      arr3->A[k] = arr2->A[j];
      k++;
      j++;
    }
  }

  for(; i<arr1->length ; i++) {
    arr3->A[k] = arr1->A[i];
    k++;
  }

  for(; j < arr2->length ; j++) {
    arr3->A[k] = arr2->A[j];
    k++;
  }

  arr3->length = arr1->length + arr2->length;
  arr3->length = 10;
  
  
}
void main() {

  struct arrayADT arr;
  printf("Enter the size of an array");
  scanf("%d", &arr.size);

  arr.A = (struct arrayADT *)malloc(arr.size * sizeof(int));

  arr.length = 0;
  int n;
  printf("enter the number of elements in an array");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("enter the elements");
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &arr.A[i]);
  }
  arr.length = n;
  display(arr);
  printf("Enter second array");
  
  int j;
  struct arrayADT *B = (struct arrayADT *)malloc((sizeof(struct arrayADT)));
  for(j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    scanf("%d", &B[j]);
  }
  struct arrayADT *arr3 = (struct arrayADT *)malloc(sizeof(struct arrayADT));
  arr3 = MergeArray(&arr, &B);
  display(*arr3);
```

I was looking to merge these arrays using heap memory and I am getting segmentation fault. I am new to C programming with pointers and I have been struck here it would be so helpful if I passed this barrier with your help.
And I am not getting where my error lies it would be helpful if someone specifies that too, so that I can avoid these errors in future.
PS: I am using minGW compiler.

Comment: You allocate memory for `arr3` but not the `A` and `B` pointers in it. You also don't return a value from your function that says it will return `struct arrayADT *`

Comment: I returned the value but still the problem is not solved. But I don't get what you say that I didn't allocate memory arr3 but not the A and B pointers in it.

Comment: I don't understand the structure of your struct. (And apparently neither do you.) Sure, the struct represents an array with lengthn and maximum capacity, but what are the `B` and `arr3` fields for? Incidentally, the names of your data members are the same as the names for the three array structs, and you mix up their use in the code.

Comment: If you switch on warnings, you will see that you are mistaken about several things: `arr.A` is not a `(struct arrayADT *)`, it's an `(int *)`. On the other hand, you can't `scanf("%d", &B[j]);`, because `B[j]` _is_ a `(struct arrayADT *)`, not an `(int *)`. That's also where your seggie occurs, because `B[1]` would the the second struct in an array of structs, but you only have one struct, `B`.

Comment: @MOehm Thank you for your response. I am a beginner to pointers so I tried a way deviating from my instructor and I got this error. Can you please correct where I made my mistakes and help me

Comment: I'd rather advise to rewrite from scratch. Your code suffers from bad organization. You have three arrays and you treat each slightly differently. For exampel, didn't you notice that the way you scan input for `B` is different from what you do for `arr`? If you `display(*B)` you should see that you haven't read the right values. Also, why is `arr` allocated on the stack and `B` is allocated on the heap? That complicates things further for no good. And there is sloppiness: `while(i < arr1->length && j < arr1->length )`, where the second test should be `j < arr2->length)`.

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `struct arrayADT *B = (struct arrayADT *)malloc((sizeof(struct arrayADT)));`  1) in C, the return type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed");`  then cleanup and exit the program.  Note: `perror()` outputs to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: regarding: `void main() {`  There are only two valid signatures for `main()`.  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  If your compiler did not tell you about this problem, then your compiler is 'non-compliant' (visual studio is a typical non-compliant compiler..

Comment: all of your `main()` function after the statement: `display(*arr3);` is missing, so we cannot reproduce the problem so we cannot help you debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, your code is rater unorganized. There are several cases for undefined behaviour, for example you don't scan in the second array correctly. The most probably candidate for your segmentaion fault is here:

```
struct arrayADT *arr3 = (struct arrayADT *)malloc((sizeof(struct arrayADT)));
```

This will give you an uninitialized chunk of memory. The length and size could of `arr3` be anything, and its data field `A` does not point to valid memory. Accessing it will likely crash.

You have three arrays in your code. You construct each step by step and you treat each differently. That leads to errors easily. Let's go about this more systematically.

Let's create a struct type for a fixed-size array: The maximum size must be given on creation and cannot change. The actual length of the array may be anything from 0 to its maximum size.

```
typedef struct Array Array;

struct Array {
  int *value;         // data array
  int length;         // actual length, 0 <= length <= size
  int size;           // maximum capacity
};
```

We create such arrays on the heap and because initializing the members is error-prone, we write a constructor:

```
Array *array_create(int size)
{
    Array *array = calloc(1, sizeof(*array));
    
    array->size = size;
    array->value = calloc(size, sizeof(*array->value));
    
    return array;
}
```

This function creates an empty array for at most `size` integers. If we allocate memory, we must de-allocate it later, so let's write a corresponding destructor function, which cleans up the ressources:

```
void array_destroy(Array *array)
{
    if (array) {
        free(array->value);
        free(array);
    }
}
```

After destroying an array, it can no longer be used, just as with memory after calling `free()` on it.

The array is at first empty, so let's write a function to add elements at its end if there is room:

```
void array_push(Array *array, int x)
{
    if (array->length < array->size) {
        array->value[array->length++] = x;
    }
}
```

And a function to print it:

```
void array_print(const Array *array)
{
    printf("[");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array->length; i++) {
        if (i) printf(", ");
        printf("%d", array->value[i]);
    }
    
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Now you can create arrays like so:

```
Array *a = array_create(10);

for (int i = 0; i < a->size; i++) {
    array_push(a, i);
}

array_print(a);
array_destroy(a);
```

Your merge function will be simpler, too. Here's a full example. (But is uses generated array, not arrays typed in by the user.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Array Array;

struct Array {
  int *value;
  int length;
  int size;
};

Array *array_create(int size)
{
    Array *array = calloc(1, sizeof(*array));
    
    array->size = size;
    array->value = calloc(size, sizeof(*array->value));
    
    return array;
}

void array_destroy(Array *array)
{
    if (array) {
        free(array->value);
        free(array);
    }
}

void array_push(Array *array, int x)
{
    if (array->length < array->size) {
        array->value[array->length++] = x;
    }
}

void array_print(const Array *array)
{
    printf("[");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array->length; i++) {
        if (i) printf(", ");
        printf("%d", array->value[i]);
    }
    
    printf("]\n");
}

Array *merge(Array *a, Array *b)
{
    Array *res = array_create(a->length + b->length);

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(i < a->length && j < b->length) {
        if(a->value[i] < b->value[j]) {
            array_push(res, a->value[i++]);
        } else {
            array_push(res, b->value[j++]);
        }
    }

    while(i < a->length) {
        array_push(res, a->value[i++]);
    }

    while(j < b->length) {
        array_push(res, b->value[j++]);
    }
    
    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    Array *a = array_create(10);
    Array *b = array_create(6);
    Array *c;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a->size; i++) {
        array_push(a, 1 + 3 * i);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < b->size; i++) {
        array_push(b, 4 + 2 * i);
    }
    
    array_print(a);
    array_print(b);
    
    c = merge(a, b);

    array_print(c);
    
    array_destroy(a);
    array_destroy(b);
    array_destroy(c);

    return 0;
}
```

If you've read so far, here's the lowdown:

- Organzie your code. That applies to code layout as much as writing small, generally applicable functions instead of doing everything "by hand". (The array type above is a bit on the fence: It uses functions, but getting at the data is still done via accessing the struct fields. You could even change the szie and length, whixh shouldn't really happen.)
- Enable compiler warnings with `-Wall`. You will get useful information about potential (and often actual) errors.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot sir. I've learnt a lot from this sir. I owe you a bunch